# load the module by require and exports are not mention in file (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following two files -

**user.server.model.js**

```
   var mongoose=require('mongoose'),
        Schema=mongoose.Schema;
       var UserSchema=new Schema({
        firstName:String,
        lastName:String,
        username:String,
        password:String,
       });

mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

And **mongoose.js**

```
var config=require('./config'),
    mongoose=require('mongoose');
    module.exports=function()
    {
        var db=mongoose.connect(config.uri);
        require('../app/models/user.server.model');
        return db;
    }
```

I have not mentioned the exports in user.server.model. **What will the final code  be** when the

```
require('../app/models/user.server.model');
```

is called.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, but if you're asking what will happen if you don't assign anything to `module.exports` in a module.  The answer to that is that it will just end up being an empty object.   So this statement:

```
require('../app/models/user.server.model');
```

will just run the code in the module (when the module is first loaded) and then `require()` will return an empty exports object.